# connection refused while trying to mount nfs

Tags: linux, nfs

Nothing I've googled out helped me yet including questions asked here.

While issuing :

```
mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.243.148:/home/nfs/ /mnt/nfs
```

I've got response

```
mount: mounting 192.168.243.148:/home/nfs/ on /mnt/nfs failed: Connection refused
```

configs I'm currently running are listed below

/etc/export :

```
/home/nfs/ 192.168.243.0/24(rw,sync,fsid=0,anonuid=0,no_root_squash,subtree_check)
```

rpcinfo -p

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100005    1   udp  56039  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  50063  mountd
    100005    2   udp  34246  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  59882  mountd
    100005    3   udp  49752  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  49991  mountd
```

showmount -e

```
Export list for mkoz-10320:
/home/nfs          192.168.243.0/24
```

iptables -L -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.243.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:111
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.243.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:111
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.243.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:111
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.243.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:2049
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.243.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:2049
```

I've disabled ufw. Not sure what else I can do.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
I don't have any problem mounting nfs on machine running nfs server.

Comment: the showmount output was from the serving server right? how about the output from `showmount -e 192.168.243.148` on the mounting machine?

Comment: `showmount: not found` life can't just be easy :B
colleague next to me can mount nfs on the same device with no problem, so I believe problem lies with my server somewhere, but I don't have any more ideas where to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried centos 7 for me also got this same **connection refused** problem..

dont worry  just run **rpcinfo -p** it shows some tcp and udp ports  you should

allow all this ports into your system firewall and retry it will works...